# jsPlumb how to remove duplicate connections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to avoid having duplicate connections (2 connections with same source and target) while using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). Is there a way to do that without having to modify the jsPlumb.js itself?

http://jsfiddle.net/uQdfq/

(drag from `task1` to `task3` **twice**)

I don't want to have the restrictions of adding specific endpoints like in ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030762/prevent-two-connections-from-sharing-the-same-anchor)).

My `.task`s are defined to be possible targets/source when they are called - that is the whole div can be a source/target, not just some endpoint:

```
  addTask($('#project1'), 'task' + 1);
```

Function itself:

```
// Adds a task div to the specific project
function addTask(parentId, id) {
  var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', id).addClass('task')

  // A title for the task
  var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text(id);
  newState.append(title);

  $(parentId).append(newState);

  // Makes the task div a possible target (i.e. connection can be dragged to)
  jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
    anchor: 'Continuous'
  });

  // Makes the task div a possible source (i.e. connection can be dragged from)
  jsPlumb.makeSource(newState, {
    anchor: 'Continuous'
  });
}
```

What would be the best way to add some condition that stops the possibility of creating duplicate connections.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LrjEC/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection',function(info){
 var con=info.connection;
 var arr=jsPlumb.select({source:con.sourceId,target:con.targetId});
 if(arr.length>1){
    jsPlumb.detach(con);
 }
});
```

Whenever a new connection is created, check to see if there is one already existing with the same source & target, if yes, then detach the new one.

Comment: Thank you. Very handy. I've made a slight adjustment so that it also checks if the current source was a target of the current target (so basically you wouldn't be able to do a reverse connection), that is: `var arr2 = jsPlumb.select({ source: con.targetId, target: con.sourceId });` then I only need to do `if (arr.length + arr2.length > 1)`

Comment: this is not the correct answer because detach(con) will not remove all the endpoints correctly under certain circumstances : http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/removing.html. A better way to do this is to check before making the connection in the first place. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959893/jsplumb-dragging-new-connection-should-remove-existing-one

Comment: @user590849 the OP never wanted to remove endpoints, your scenario might be different.

Comment: I am getting an error like this: jsPlumb: fire failed for event connection : TypeError: jsPlumb.detach is not a function. what to do?